# Does X11 still have a hardcoded limit for application resource strings?

Tags: x11, xorg, xterm, x-resources

The xterm(1) manual page states:

> Due to **a hardcoded limit in the X libraries on the total number of resources (to 400)**, the resources for 256-colors are omitted when wide-character support  and  luit  are  enabled. Besides inconsistent  behavior  if  only  part  of  the  resources were allowed, determining the exact cutoff is difficult, and  the X libraries  tend to crash if the number of resources exceeds the limit. The color palette is  still  initialized  to  the  same default values, and can be modified via control sequences.

I suspect that this information is dated. Can anyone confirm that this is (or is not any more) a problem for a contemporary X implementation like X.Org 1.12 (X11R7)? Where in the X11 sources would someone need to look for this limit, if it still exists?

Comment: What is the date on the Xorg/xterm man page?

Comment: @eyoung100 That's xterm patch 313 from 28 November 2014. Look for the first occurrence of "400".

Comment: My man page is from September 10,2013, and contains the warning, and yours is newer meaning the limit is most likely still valid

Comment: @eyoung100 Well, I didn't dig into all the patches, but I have a gut feeling that this paragraph goes way back to the 1980's. A lot of X development has happened since then and a lot of limitations are no more. Is this one of them?

Comment: The warning was added in 2009

> Patch #250 - 2009/10/13

>document in xterm manpage the limited availability of resources color16 to color255 as noted in patch #188 (Ubuntu #438850).

The FTP only goes back as far as 223 so out of luck looking for 188 for comparison.

Comment: Hmm, changelog for 188 say that they implemented a workaround "modify initialization of 256- and 88-colors so that colors beyond 16 are normally not X resources. This works around a hard-coded limit in Xt which breaks xterm when 256-colors and luit are both configured (report by Noah Friedman)."

Comment: @CthulhuTentacles Thanks for the research. I have found the answer: The limit still exists. The hardcoded limit is in the X toolkit library, libXt, specifically in `src/Resource.c` the macro definition `#define MAXRESOURCES 400`. Please feel free to make this an answer and collect the bounty. I'm happy to give you the bounty since you went to considerable effort to investigate. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to [xorg/lib/libXt/Resource.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXt/tree/src/Resources.c#n480)

```
#define MAXRESOURCES  400
```

used later in the [same file](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXt/tree/src/Resources.c#n507):

```
} else if (num_resources >= MAXRESOURCES) {
    XtAppWarningMsg(XtWidgetToApplicationContext(widget),
    "invalidResourceCount","getResources",XtCXtToolkitError,
          "too many resources",
      (String *)NULL, (Cardinal *)NULL);
return NULL;
```

Xorg developers are unlikely to change this because few applications *could* use that many resources.

The original scheme for 256-colors in xterm (in [1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_111)) assigned a separate resource to each color.

The changelog for [Patch #188 - 2004/5/12 - XFree86 4.4.99.6](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_188) says:

> - modify initialization of 256- and 88-colors so that colors beyond 16 are normally not X resources. This works around a hard-coded limit in Xt which breaks xterm when 256-colors and luit are both configured (report by Noah Friedman).

The report mentioned `luit`, but along with that, there were other resources for UTF-8, locale, etc.  Some tuning is needed on occasion, e.g.,[Patch #191 - 2004/6/6 - XFree86 4.4.99.7](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_191)

> - fix ifdef's for `OPT_COLOR_RES2` so that the fake resource table introduced in patch #188 is not compiled if it is empty. This happened to work with gcc (report by Joel Konkle-Parker).

and [Patch #250 - 2009/10/13](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_250):

> - improve the workaround from patch #188 by enabling resources for the 88-color model.
> - document in xterm manpage the limited availability of resources color16 to color255 as noted in patch #188 (Ubuntu #438850).

The program can still be built with 256 color resources (and no UTF-8), but that's done less often now.

Just as a sanity check, xterm has this chunk (turned on when debugging):

```
TRACE(("VTInitialize wnew %p, %d / %d resources\n",
       (void *) wnew, XtNumber(xterm_resources), MAXRESOURCES));
assert(XtNumber(xterm_resources) < MAXRESOURCES);
```

and the trace log shows

```
VTInitialize wnew 0xb98a90, 232 / 400 resource
```

so there's no immediate risk of running out of resources, now that the extra 240 (256-16) color resources are not used.